# TFlite model_maker train_data size=0

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, training-data, image-classification

I have been recently trying to train an object_detection model using tflite_modelmaker, the problem comes as I try to initialize training. The train _data size comes to be zero though there are around 440 items in it.

Here is the code

```
model = object_detector.create(train_data = training_data,batch_size =4,model_spec=spec,train_whole_model=True,epochs=20,validation_data = validation_data)
```

And here is the error it throws:

> ValueError: The size of the train_data (0) couldn't be smaller than
> batch_size (4). To solve this problem, set the batch_size smaller or
> increase the size of the train_data.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to do with your data pipeline. Ie images aren't loading into the model.

Double check how you are using the DataLoader function and what you are assigning to `train_data` `test_data` and `validation_data`

If you haven't changed any of the variables from the DataLoader this is the default create/train function:

```
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=8, train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)
```

I'd start by changing `train_data = training_data` to just `train_data`